# Incompatible magic value error

Tags: java, classloader, magic-numbers

I was following an example from the following link:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-indepth.html?page=1
and this is an output I am getting:

```
This program will use SimpleClassLoader.
        >>>>>> Load class : TestClass
        >>>>>> Not a system class.
        >>>>>> Fetching the implementation of TestClass
file was read successfully
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1768779887 in class file 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at aha.SimpleClassLoader.loadClass(SimpleClassLoader.java:80)
    at aha.SimpleClassLoader.loadClass(SimpleClassLoader.java:42)
    at aha.Example.main(Example.java:11)
```

here is an example of my method that reads a file:

```
 private byte getClassImplFromDataBase(String className)[] {
        System.out.println("        >>>>>> Fetching the implementation of "+className);
        byte result[];
        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:/delete/"+className+".impl");
            result = new byte[fi.available()];
            fi.read(result);
            System.out.println("file was read succesfullyl");
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            /*
             * If we caught an exception, either the class wasnt found or it
             * was unreadable by our process.
             */
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I placed TestClass.impl file under C:/delete directory .
My classes reside under package: aha
So the file TestClass.impl is read ok, but something happens during the 
  result = defineClass(classData, 0, classData.length);
I know this method is deprecated but still ??

Comment: The file is not a valid class. What is in your TestClass.impl ? It should be a .class file. Also, reading a file to .availiable() won't read the whole file.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ `.available()` happens to work this way for files smaller than 2GB but its not guaranteed to work. It doesn't work for any other stream type.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what file type `.impl` is but I suspect it not a class file which contains byte code.  The magic number `1768779887` in hex is `696D706F` or `impo` in ASCII. (The first four bytes of `import` I suspect)

So it would appear to me that you are trying to load uncompiled Java code whcih you cannot do (that is what the compiler is for)  You are better of using the Compiler API, but I suspect you really need something like OSGi as trying to load classes your self requires you to have a very detailed understanding of how class loading work.

Comment: +1 for spotting the problem and recommending OSGi as a sane solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar error with a regular struts2 project, **solved cleaning the project**.

```
8266 ERROR [main]: Excepción arrancando filtro struts2
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file com/lm/action/musician/MusicianList
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1650)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:108)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:424)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:378)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:536)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
8266 ERROR [main]: Excepción arrancando filtro struts2
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file com/lm/action/musician/MusicianList
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1650)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:108)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:424)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:378)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:536)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
abr 19, 2013 10:32:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
abr 19, 2013 10:32:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```